# What classes have greater-than-full-caster progression?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class, spellcasting

For example, Ur-Priest gains the next level of spell at every class level (instead of every other class level, like cleric). Are there any other classes (of any type) that get higher-level spells more quickly like this?

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146754/is-it-possible-to-consistently-get-spell-levels-faster-than-clerics-or-wizards).

Comment: Chameleon at level 10 (so character level 15) has a caster level of 20 (knows less spells than a full caster at level 15 but has more caster levels) (caster level is 2*chameleon Level)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very short list of full, accelerated casters:

- **Ur Priest** - like a Cleric, but in 10 levels
- **Beholder Mage** - like a wizard in ten levels that also breaks the action economy
- **Blighter** - Druid spellcasting in 10 levels, but off a much smaller, eviler list
- **Apostle of Peace**  1-9 in 10 levels; technically playable; wrecks parties.  Casts off a short list of “good” themed spells.
- **Divine Crusader** casts off a single domain list (only), but gets them all in 10 levels.

As @KRyan noted in comments, most of these classes go 10 levels, but hit 9th level spells at the 9th class level (which is a title case Big Deal — 9th level spells are a quantum leap in power)

There are also a couple that start with higher level spells:

- **Sublime Chord** - combination of bard and wizard, 4th-9th level spells in 10 levels
- **Nar Demonbinder** - a small, broken spell list going 4th-8th in 7 levels.

Comment: Apostle of Peace? Divine Crusader?

Comment: Nar demonbinder doesn’t get 9th-level spells; it only has 7 class levels and caps at 8th-level spells at 7th. It is *slightly* accelerated—you qualify by having 4th-level spells, and then get 5th-level spells at 1st level. So you get 5th-level spells at ECL 8th instead of 9th, and then each spell level is gained one character level earlier than a single-classed fullcaster.

Comment: You might want to mention that most of those “1-9 in 10 levels” classes actually get to 9th-level spells by 9th level.